# Cannot run .JSON on response from the Fetch API

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, express, fetch-api

I am working with React, Express, PostgreSQL, Node, and the Fetch API. When I try to run a "GET" request (within a `try` block) to get data from my database, the request fails (and enters the `catch` block) with the following error:

```
Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

Here is the failing code that I have on the front end:

```
const getRequests = async () => {
    try {
      const responseInfo = await fetch("/api/advice-requests", {
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json" },
      });

      if (responseInfo.status === 200) {
        console.log("200 running"); // This is logged to the console.

        const data = await responseInfo.json();

        console.log("data :", data); // This is NOT logged to the console. It fails.

        setAdviceRequests(data.requests);
        setResponses(data.responses);

        return;
      }
      
    } catch (error_o) {

      // The UI is updated with the text of the below error

      setError(
        "Something went wrong on our end. We are looking into how we can improve..."
      );

      return;
    }
  };
```

Here is some of my server code (there is more, but it is not relevant), including some changes I made that worked to solve this problem for other people.

```
const adviceRequests = require("./controllers/adviceRequests");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.options("*", cors());

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../build")));
  app.get("/*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../build", "index.html"));
  });
}

app.get("/api/advice-requests", adviceRequests.getAll);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`SERVER RUNNING ON ${PORT}.`);
});
```

Lastly, here is the `adviceRequests.getAll` function:

```
getAll: async (req, res) => {
    const db = req.app.get("db");

    try {
      let requests = await db.requests.getAll(req.session.user.id);
      let responses = await db.responses.getAll([req.session.user.id]);

      return res.status(200).send([requests, responses]);

    } catch (error) {

      return res.status(500).send({
        message:
          "Something went wrong on our end. We are looking into how we can improve.",
          error,
      });
    }
  },
```

A bit more information:

- The code works just fine when I run it locally
- Even on the live server, I can successfully run several POST requests for authentication and *adding* requests. I just cannot *get* them.
- I have done quite a bit of research into this and am posting my own as a last resort. Nothing that has worked for other people has worked for me so far.

Answer (score 1):

Everytime I have had this "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0" it was because i was trying to parse an html plain response as if it was a json. Note that every html file starts with a <.

I suggest you change this `console.log("200 running");` with a `console.log(responseInfo);`, that way you'll notice if the response is a json or not.

From what I see, the problem might be the order in which the app.get are defined. Note that express serves first come first served, so since you have already defined an app.get("/*"), everything will be served by that route. Also note that you are sending back an index.html, which matches the issue shown in the frontend.

Comment: It was the order!! Thank you so much!! I have spent around 8 hours trying different solutions, and moving the app.get("/*") below the other requests is all it took. I appreciate you taking the time to read and answer that question.